# Let $f:X \to Y $ a continuous function, where $(X, \tau_X)$ is $T_2$ and first countable and let $D$ dense in X, then $f(D) \cap f(X-D)= \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that if $f:X \to Y $ is a continuous function, where $(X, \tau_{X})$ is $T_2$ and first countable and let $D$ dense in X such that $f|_D : (D, \tau_D) \to (f(D), \tau_{f(D)})$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(D) \cap f(X-D)= \emptyset$

**My idea:** Suppose that $ y \in f(D) \cap f(X-D)$ then exists $a \in D$ such that $f(a)=y$ and exists $b \in X-D$ such that $f(b)=y$. Since $a \in D$ and $b \in X-D$ then $a \neq b$ and since $X$ is $T_2$ exist $U$ and $V$ open in $X$ such that $a \in U$ and $b \in V$. Then $a \in D \cap U \in \tau_D$ and since $f|_D$ is open we have $f|_D (D \cap U) \in \tau_{f(D)}$

And this is what I've done and I don't know how to continue